# Ubuntu 18.10 hoards 9GB RAM that don't show up in htop

Tags: ram, memory-usage

This is my htop output right after boot.
[image: This is my htop output right after boot.]
I have no idea what all this RAM is being used for. How can i figure out what's using all of that memory and put a stop to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command to see the top ten processes for memory usage. Post that to start with:

```
ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR<=10{print $0}'
```

Full disclosure, I stole that from another answer. Anyways, lets start there.

Comment: Thank you. Unlike htop or sudo htop, this really outputs values for all users.
Apparently the Cassandra install i did last week and did not get around to doing anything with yet was eating up more than 26% of my RAM to do god only knows what with.
Stopped the service with `service cassandra stop` and, hopefully, prevented further autostart with `update-rc.d cassandra disable`

Comment: Nice. Glad it worked out.